# Youtube Iframe function that opens website at end of youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Is there a function in the Youtube IFRAME API that can execute a command, such as opening a website at the end of a played video?

(I believe there was a function that could do that under the old Java API but that was deprecated last year.)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [IFrame Player API - Events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) for the different functions that you can use. However, based from this [forum thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/UwT-KbqcFzM), you cannot redirect to a URL when using the standard embed code given on YouTube videos. That has to be done using javascripts and html.

You can try the given setup wherein an Event Listener is used to listen for the `onStateChange` event in the video player with value of 0 (zero) or `YT.PlayerState.ENDED` which indicates that the video has finished. Then you redirect to a URL using JS.

For more details, please go through the given documentation and thread.

This other related forum - [Redirect to another URL after embedded YouTube video ends - possible?](http://www.warriorforum.com/programming/35546-redirect-another-url-after-embedded-youtube-video-ends-possible.html) might also help you with your concern.